# Accessing y-coordinates in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

I have a list of pairs where the list resembles li = [(a,b), (c,d), ... , (t, u)]. I am attempting to index into the y-coordinates of each tuple to count how many tuples have a y-coordinate of 0, 1, or 2 but am unsure of how to do so. Calling li[i] only returns (a,b) but not the specific coordinate (b) I want. I have searched similar questions, so I was able to get a bit of the list comprehension but am still not able to process the loop. My code currently looks like this:

```
for i in range(len(li)):
    if (x,y) for x, y in li if y == 0:
        zero_count += 1
    elif (x,y) for x, y in li if y == 1:
        one_count += 1
    # if y-coordinate = 2
    else:
        two_count += 1
```

Comment: nested indexing li[i][j], more fun using zip(*li) in a for loop or comprehension

Comment: @f5r5e5d using zip would mean there are 2 separate lists for x and y coordinates respectively. Your idea of fun is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the tuple with

```
li[i]
```

To get the second element, you add a subscript to *that* expression:

```
li[i][1]
```

Note that your "unpacking" reference is a good idea in other circumstances, effectively using

```
x, y = li[i]
```

to grab both elements in one assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. I am currently getting this error "TypeError: 'sage.rings.integer.Integer' object is not iterable". Would you happen to know why this error is occurring? It seems like this is due to the first line in the for loop but I am unsure.

Comment: Not really, since (1) that's not at all part of the code you posted; (2) you haven't posted the entire error message (which does indicate the line); (3) a separate problem should be posted in a separate question.  However, the easy way to check is to put a simple **print** in front of your **for** statement: print out the thing to the right of the **in** keyword and see what it is.  The error is telling you that this thing is not a sequence it can iterate through.  It's likely a simple integer, rather than a list of tuples, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack a tuple from a list - by using `for (a,b) in li` type syntax. This code should do what your code is trying to do :

```
counts = [0,0,0]

for (x,y) in li:
    counts[y] +=1
```

Assumes that the y co-ord can only be 0,1 or 2 - as implied by your post

Answer (score 0):

if you're using range for your for loop, this will return your y values:

```
for i in range(len(li)):
    print li[i][1]
```

if you don't need the li index, you can also do:

```
for i in li:
    print i[1]
```

Comment: If you do need the index and the element from a list or other iterable - it is far better to use `enumerate` rather than use `range(len(<iterable>))`

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Interesting. I'm assuming you mean using `for i, l in enumerate(li)`. Would you care to elaborate why it's far better than using `range()`?

Comment: You may well have heard of something called the `zen of python`, and something called `pythonic` code - `enumerate` is considered far more pythonic - firstly it is gives you direct access to the element of the list - without needing two functions, and then index into the list. For people who are used to Python, then `enumerate` is more readable - where as forcing a for loop to count numbers (by using `range(len(li))` is considered trying to make python like C. For large lists, enumerate does seem to have a slightly better performance too - but the improvement is narrow.